# Can I set EventData.PartitionKey while sending to EventHubs using a PartitionSender?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-eventhub

I currently have an EventHub instance set up in Azure. It has 5 partitions. What I want to know if if the `PartitionKey` always has to be a number between `0` and `n-1` with `n` being the number of partitions.

I have the following code:

```
    private static async Task SendMessagesToEventHub(int numMessagesToSend)
    {
        var sender = eventHubClient.CreatePartitionSender("test1");

        for (var i = 0; i < numMessagesToSend; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                var message = $"Message {i}";
                Console.WriteLine($"Sending message: {message}");
               await  sender.SendAsync(new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message)));
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} > Exception: {exception.Message}");
            }

            await Task.Delay(10);
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"{numMessagesToSend} messages sent.");
    }
```

This the throws an exception

> The specified partition is invalid for an EventHub partition sender or receiver. It should be between 0 and 4.

In the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-programming-guide) of EventHub, this is what they say regarding the `PartitionKey`:

> The EventData class has a PartitionKey property that enables the sender to specify a value that is hashed to produce a partition assignment. Using a partition key ensures that all the events with the same key are sent to the same partition in the Event Hub. **Common partition keys include user session IDs and unique sender ID**s.

To me this means that you are not limited to an `int` but can use any `string`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Answer**:

You cannot mix `PartitionKey` and `PartitionSender` - they are 2 ***mutually exclusive*** concepts.

Don't use a `PartitionSender` aka `ehClient.CreatePartitionSender()` - API, which was designed to send to a specific partition (in which case EventHub service cannot use the `PartitionKey` to-hash-to anymore).

Instead, use this code snippet in `c#`:

```
EventData myEvent = new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));
myEvent.PartitionKey = "test1";
await eventHubClient.SendAsync(myEvent);
```

We learned that this was a bit confusing API to grasp for our customers and then when we did our `Java` SDK, we corrected/simplified our API to look like this:

```
EventData myEvent = new EventData(message.getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset()))
eventHubClient.SendSync(myEvent, "test1");
```

***The 3 types of Send Patterns Exposed by Event Hubs:***

When we developed EventHubs service - we wanted to give multiple levels of control on Partitioning their event stream - to our users. We came up with the below 3 modes (our `c#` client API's):

1. [EventHubClient.Send(eventData_**Without**_PartitionKey)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventhubclient#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_EventHubClient_Send_Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_EventData_) - use this when you don't want any control on how data is partitioned. EventHubs service will try to distribute data uniformly across all partitions (best-effort, no guarantees). As, you **traded off** having **control on partitioning your data** - what you gain here is **high-availability**. If you have an Event Hub with 32 partitions - and are using this method of sending to Event Hubs - your event will be delivered to one of the 32 Event Hubs partitions that is immediately available & have least data on it.
2. [EventHubClient.Send(eventData_**With**_PartitionKey)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventhubclient#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_EventHubClient_Send_Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_EventData_) - use this when you have a property on your data - using which you want to partition your data. EventHubs service will make sure all `EventData`s with same `PartitionKey` will land on the same `EventHubs partition`. Here - user controls partitioning by specifying a hint - using which our service will run a hash algorithm and deliver to the hashed partition. All events with the same `PartitionKey` are guaranteed to land on the same `Event Hubs partition`.
3. [EventHub**Sender**.Send(eventData_Without_PartitionKey)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventhubsender#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_EventHubSender_Send_Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_EventData_) - ***EventHubPartitionSender*** name would have been more apt for this - use this when you want complete control on Partitioning your data - when you need control on - which `EventData` should land on which `EventHubs partition`. This is typically used - when customers have their own proprietary hash algorithm - which they believe to perform better, for their scenarios - w.r.to. fairness of load distribution across all `EventHubs partitions`.

What you need is (2).

[here's some general reading on Event Hubs concepts...](https://medium.com/@sreeramg/what-is-microsoft-azure-event-hubs-1ec100452067)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I don't like the way that it is set up but at least I understand now.

Comment: Thanks for acknowledging @DavidPilkington. Agreed, Ideally we should have used a diff. term like shardId insteadof partitionId.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the default Round-robin logic and wants to evenly distribute the message to all partitions using your custom logic you can use a similar way to send a message to particular Partition Id, You should cannot assign Partition key for the eventData in this case.

You have to figure out a logic to get the PartitionId to distribute your message to all partitions

```
    String PartitionId = GetPartitionId(message) 
    EventData eventData = new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));     
    EventHubClient.CreatePartitionedSender(PartitionId).SendAsync(eventData)

    private static int GetPartitionId(Message message)
    {
       // Your own custom logic
        var svin = message.vin.Substring(12, 5);
        int partKey;
        if (int.TryParse(svin, out partKey))
        {
            partKey = Convert.ToInt32(svin) % NumberOfPartitions;
        }
        return partKey;
    }
```

Or you can set Partition key for EventData and Eventhub will distribute it to different Paritions. But Eventdata with same Parition key will go to the same Partition ID

```
      string payLoadJson = convertToJson(record);
      EventData eventData = new 
      EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payLoadJson));
      eventData.PartitionKey = record.vin;
      
      await eventHubClient.SendAsync(eventData);
```