# What is the partition key used by Azure Diagnostic Settings when sending data to Event Hub?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-monitoring, azure-diagnostics

**When configuring a diagnostic settings for a resource in Azure, and configuring that diagnostic setting to an event hub, what is the partition key used when messages are published to the event hub? Or is no partition key used (resulting in round-robin distribution across partitions)?** I've searched through Microsoft documentation and haven't been able to find an answer to this question.

The specific use case we have is an application insights resource which has a diagnostic setting configured to send data to an event hub. We then have an Azure stream analytics job consuming from this event hub. We're trying to understand how data will be partitioned across that event hub so we can properly configure the partition key for the stream analytics job input.

Comment: it would be great if you provide more details like your setup and approach. Then only community members can answer.

Comment: The question includes the specific use case of app insights -> diagnostic setting -> event hub -> azure stream analytics. Is there specific information you're thinking that I can add?

Comment: The partition key is not used to partition the data in the event hub, but it can be used to group related events into a single partition. You can specify the partition key in the Stream Analytics job input configuration.

Comment: Event hub does have a number of partitions as its configuration. When any data is sent to an event hub (including diagnostic settings), there is some determination as to which partition that data is going to (even if it's round-robin because no partition key is provided). I'm trying to understand if there is a partition key at all (would save me from potentially re-partitioning data in ASA), and if so what is it? If there isn't a partition key provided that's ok too, I just would like to know. I've also updated my original post to denote I understand no partition key is an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diagnostic Settings (Azure Monitor) will not set any Partition key for the events, hence the events will be load balanced in a round robin fashion across all the Event Hub partitions.
You should do the same from the Stream Analytics side, and pull from all partitions.

Answer (score 0):

I do agree with @Jdresc you should do this from Stream Analytics side.

Refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42493951/can-i-set-eventdata-partitionkey-while-sending-to-eventhubs-using-a-partitionsen#:%7E:text=The%20EventData%20class%20has%20a%20PartitionKey%20property%20that,user%20session%20IDs%20and%20unique%20sender%20ID%20s.) link to get more information about partition key.

- When configuring a diagnostic setting for a resource in Azure, and configuring that diagnostic setting to an event hub, **the partition key used when messages are published to the event hub is derived from the diagnostic setting's resource ID**.
- Refer this [Github](https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/event-hubs/event-hubs-programming-guide.md) document. According this document,

> The Event Data class has a Partition Key property that enables the
> sender to specify a value that is hashed to produce a partition
> assignment. Using a partition key ensures that all the events with the
> same key are sent to the same partition in the Event Hub. Common
> partition keys include user session IDs and unique sender IDs.

- If you do not provide a value for Partition Key, sent events are distributed to partitions using a round-robin model.
  [image]
- Thanks to @Jdresc for leading into right direction. As he said do this from stream analytics side as No partition key will be set by diagnostic settings for the events. Therefore, you should configure the partition key for the Stream Analytics job.

Comment: Just curious, where did you get that information from ? it doesn't seem accurate because if the partition key was the resource name, that would cause all events to land in a single partition due to the Event Hub partition assignment algorithm.

I just tested witha  few resources sending diagnostics to Event Hub and the partition is always empty, if you can provide the doc you found those statements from, that would be great.